# How to find the empids of employees who joined their department before their manager

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to find out the employees who joined before their manager. How can I solve this?
My schema is as below.

```
Employee (EmpId, DeptId,MgrId,Salary, DateOfJoining)
```

**First Solution:-**

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.EmpId AS Empid
FROM Employee e
INNER JOIN Employee m
ON e.MgrId = m.Empid
AND e.DateofJoining < m.DateOfJoining;
```

**Second solution :-**

```
SELECT A.EmpId,A.DateOfJoining
FROM Employee A,
(
SELECT DISTINCT e.EmpId,m.Empid AS MgrID,m.DOJ 
FROM Employee e,Employee m 
WHERE e.MgrId = m.Empid
) B
WHERE A.EmpId = B.EmpId 
  AND A.DateOfJoining < B.DateOfJoining;
```

Comment: Use a select statement to do it.

Comment: What's wrong with your current query? It seems to give the correct output, at least if you're only interested in immediate managers and not all managers above in the hierarchy (that is managers of managers)

Comment: Just got the solnn guys...

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong..

Comment: @SOaddict Maybe I'm missing something but apart from adding the date to the output the second query seems to do exactly what the first did, only slightly less efficient.

Comment: Yup you are right..... :) If I add distinct that would solve the problem...

Comment: @SOaddict You shouldn't need distinct in the first query if employees have a 0-to-1 relation with managers (that is, an emp cannot have multiple mgrs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need a self join to do this.

```
SELECT e.*  --* to return all details, if needed
FROM Employee e
LEFT JOIN Employee m ON e.MgrId = m.Empid
WHERE m.Empid is not null
AND e.DateofJoining < m.DateOfJoining;
```

alternatively you could do this with an inner join-

```
SELECT e.*  --* to return all details, if needed
FROM Employee e
INNER JOIN Employee m ON e.MgrId = m.Empid AND e.DateofJoining < m.DateOfJoining;
```

the difference between putting the WHERE clause conditions in the join is that the join will only occur where the conditions are met, instead of joining on 1 condition and then filtering.  Personally I try to do this as little as possible.

Comment: Maybe you don't know this, but both queries will be treated as inner joins and have identical execution plans. The where predicate in the first effectively changes the query from a left to an inner join.

Comment: @jpw yes, I am just showing the different syntax.  It's all preference.  Should have exactly the same results.

Answer (score 0):

The question is: `Display all the employees who have joined before their managers`

The answer is:

```
SELECT E1.ENAME FROM EMP E1,EMP E2 
WHERE E1.MGR=E2.EMPNO 
AND E1.MGR < E2.MGR;
```